# Need to calculate number of valid domain names between two other domain names

Tags: algorithms

A domain name can be 2 to 32 characters in length.

- The first character can be the characters 'a' through 'z'
- The last    character can be the characters 'a' through 'z' or '0'
  through '9'
- The middle characters can be 'a' through 'z', '0' through '9' or a dash '-'

so all the following examples of a valid domain name :-

- aa
- a-a
- a9
- microsoft
- google

These would be invalid:-

- 99redballons ==> invalid because it starts with a number
- adash- ==> invalid because it ends with a dash

So suppose I treat a domain name as a base 37 number (afterall, there are 37 possible characters a-b, 0-9, and dash) then in theory i can count through all of them. If I start with dash '-' as zero and 'a' as one and 'b' as 2 etc then

- aa = 1 x 37 + 1 = 38
- ab = 1 x 37 + 2 = 29

etc etc.

Now given two arbitrary domain names I can tell how many names are between then by converting to decimal and doing a subtraction.

My problem is, how do I account for the invalid domain names?

What is the best way to approach this to generate a formula or an algo?